# NextJS App Router API for json stored in public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, httprequest

I am using Nextjs 13 App Router to GET and POST data stored in public/internalData.json.

The GET API works fine, but the POST not with error below:

> error RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 0

Here is my code:

```
import path from "path";
import { promises as fs } from "fs";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  // Find the absolute path of the JSON directory
  const jsonDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), "public");

  // Read the JSON data file 'internalData.json'
  const fileContents = await fs.readFile(
    path.join(jsonDirectory, "internalData.json"),
    "utf8"
  );

  // Parse the content to remove escape characters
  const jsonData = JSON.parse(fileContents);

  // Return the content of the data file in JSON format
  return NextResponse.json(jsonData);
}

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    const jsonDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), "public");

    const fileContents = await fs.readFile(
      path.join(jsonDirectory, "internalData.json"),
      "utf8"
    );

    const jsonData = JSON.parse(fileContents);

    const requestBody = await request.json();

    const linkData = requestBody.links;

    jsonData.links = linkData;

    const updatedJsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2);

    await fs.writeFile(
      path.join(jsonDirectory, "internalData.json"),
      updatedJsonData,
      "utf8"
    );

    const response = new NextResponse();
    response.init({
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    response.send(updatedJsonData);

    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("POST request error:", error);
    return NextResponse.error(error);
  }
}
```

I hope I could GET and POST data in the public folder JSON file directly.